# is using a base class for entites a good idea?

Tags: java, hibernate

I read [this article](http://ocpsoft.org/java/hibernate-use-a-base-class-to-map-common-fields/)
about a base class for hibernate entities.

Is is nowadays a good idea to use a base class for common fields like id, version, create_at, create_by, etc.?

What about hashcode and equals-Methods? I do not like to use the id field for my equals methods.

Is it possible to solve this by composition? 
What are the downsides?

Answer (score 3):

While using a base class for entities has a lot of uses, for mapping common fields I'd rather do it by embedding:

1. Define a class with your common fields and mark it as [`@Embeddable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html).
2. In the containing Entity, add a reference to the "embeddable" class, and mark the reference as [`@Embedded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html) or [`@EmbeddedId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html), whatever applies.
3. When applicable, mark the reference with additional [@AttributeOverrides](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverrides.html) or [`@AssociationOverrides`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverrides.html) to customize the mapping.

The main problem I see with [`@MappedSuperclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) (the approach used in your linked post) is that you can only have a superclass per entity. This might be fine in many use cases, but it is too inflexible for the most complex ones. Embedding gives you the flexibility to combine as many `@Embeddable`s as you want. The tradeoff is that it is not transparent. If you had:

```
select u.streetname from User u
```

And move `streetname` to an embedded `address`, now you will have to do:

```
select u.address.streetname from User u
```

In the end, if you know your model is simple, `@MappedSuperclass` will do the trick. If you have a complex model you can benefit from `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only work with attached instances and in a single session, you shouldn't have to implement `hashCode()` or `equals()`. Because in this case there is always only one instance per row.

You also can write your own `hashCode()` or `equals()` methods in subclasses, not calling the methods from the superclass.

Sources: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-identity